# Formatting like R in Latex document

Tags: r

I'm an extreme beginner. I would like to write the names of R packages like "lavaan" in the screenshot attached, but I really don't know how to achieve that. Can anyone help? I would only format one word at a time like this.
[image]

Comment: `\texttt{lavaan}`

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think there's a way to automatically format just like R code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "a way to automatically format just like R code".

Comment: sorry I do not understand your question. LaTeX has to be told which font to use.  Just as in R markdown you must have marked `lavaan` in some way, it did not automatically become monospaced.

Comment: If you're going to use a particular name like that a lot in your document, then in the preamble you could include a macro for it: `\newcommand{\lavaan}{\texttt{lavaan}}`.

Comment: @murray that is what I meant! Thank you so much, this will save me some amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list the packages of a R session automatically, with the required format:

[image: mwe]

**test.Rnw** in Rstudio (or **test.Rtex** in Overleaf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<foo,echo=F>>=

library(xtable)   # loaded only for test
library(ggplot2)  # loaded only for test

@

\subsection*{A hard R work} 


<<morefoo,echo=T>>=
2+3
@

\subsection*{Materials and Methods} 

<<info,echo=F>>=
a <- knitr::combine_words(.packages(), 
before = "\\texttt{", after ="}")
@

For this hard work we used the 
\Sexpr{sessionInfo()$R.version$version.string} 
with  the  packages \Sexpr{a}.

\end{document}
```